# How to access current class variable in an overridden method of an interface, which is being set using a setter in current class

Tags: typescript

very recently i have moved my firebase functions from js to ts.
and i have started loving ts so much because it make the work so easier as we can use OOPS in it.

well,
i m not new to OOPS as i know java. but in ts the syntax is quite different and i have not become so much familiar with it.

here is one class i have written.

## my problem is :

how to refer the onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener inside the overridden function when i return data from database reference.

I am using VS code and when i click on this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener in that overridden method it doesnt take me to its original variable and when i m running the code i get an error {TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener' of undefined : }. it means 'this' is undefined.

as i said i know java so i m using java kind of approach to make the code work. but it doesnt work that way in ts.

please help if someone knows about this

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListenerModule = require("../interfaces/OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListener");

const TAG = "UnAuthToken";

export class UnAuthToken {

    private onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener: OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListenerModule.OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListener;

    setOnUnAuthTokenGenerationListener(onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener: OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListenerModule.OnUnAuthTokenGenerationListener) {
        this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener = onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener;
    }

    init(deviceId: string) {

        let accessToken = this.generateSecurityToken();

        let app = admin.app();
        let accessTokenRef = app.database('https://firebaseio.com/').ref('/Tokens/ApiAccessTokens');
        
        accessTokenRef.child(deviceId).set(accessToken,
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(TAG, error);
                    if (this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener != null) {
                        this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener.onError("Something went wrong");
                    }

                } else {

                    if (this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener != null) {
                        this.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener.onTokenGenerated(deviceId);
                    }

                }
            }
        );
    }

    generateSecurityToken() {
        let text = "";
        let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `this` changes when you call it from within the anonymous function.

To make sure the value if this is the same inside the anonymous function you can assign `this` to a variable outside the function and use that variable inside that function.

```
  init(deviceId: string) {
    let self = this;

    let app = admin.app();
    let accessTokenRef = app
      .database("https://firebaseio.com/")
      .ref("/Tokens/ApiAccessTokens");

    accessTokenRef.child(deviceId).set(accessToken, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        if (self.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener != null) {
          self.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener.onError("Something went wrong");
        }
      } else {
        if (self.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener != null) {
          self.onUnAuthTokenGenerationListener.onTokenGenerated(deviceId);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```